# Add note with text in 3D plot

Tags: tikz-3dplot, tikz-node

I basically want to use this command `\node at (0.1,0.1) { \colorbox{white}{\textcolor{black}{$A$}}};` and just add one dimension for 3D. Unfortunately this does not work and the internet just explains to me how I do vectors and lines, but not simple nodes. What is the easiest way here?

Thank you for your help.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8}
\begin{document} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[grid=major,view={210}{30},
ymin=0,
 ymax=10,
 xmin=0,
 xmax=10,   
 zmin=0,
 zmax=1200,          
         xtick={0,10},
 xticklabels={{10},{0}},
  ytick={0,10},
   ztick={0,1200},
 ,colormap/blackwhite, rotate around z=20
    ]

    \addplot3+[mesh,scatter,samples=10,domain=0:10] 
        {y^3};

\addplot3 [data cs=cart,surf,domain=0:10,samples=2, opacity=0.5]
      {x^3};        

    \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It does work and becomes much easier if you switch to a newer version, where you do not need `axis cs:`.

Comment: Hi, I run version 5.0.4 of Texmaker. And \node at (0.1,0.1,0.1) { \colorbox{white}{\textcolor{black}{$A$}}}; does not work :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the more recent versions of pgfplots you no longer need `axis cs:`. I have no idea about TeXMaker.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.16}
\begin{document} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[grid=major,view={210}{30},
ymin=0,
 ymax=10,
 xmin=0,
 xmax=10,   
 zmin=0,
 zmax=1200,          
         xtick={0,10},
 xticklabels={{10},{0}},
  ytick={0,10},
   ztick={0,1200},
 ,colormap/blackwhite, rotate around z=20
    ]

    \addplot3+[mesh,scatter,samples=10,domain=0:10] 
        {y^3};

\addplot3 [data cs=cart,surf,domain=0:10,samples=2, opacity=0.5]
      {x^3};        
    \node[fill=white,anchor=north east] at (0.1,0.1,1000) {$A$};
    \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It was just me being unable to use the right coordinates, sry.